# Need to display cell item from a loop horizontally

Tags: php, css

Trying to create a broad sheet for a school such that it loops the result database and fetches a student records and display it horizontally.

**css controlling the style for the ul**

```
#my-list{
    background: #f7f7f; 
    padding: 8px; /* Give the items some air to breathe */
}

#my-list > li {
    display: inline-block;
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline;
    background:#99FFFF;
    /* this fix is needed for IE7- */
}

#my-list > li > a{
    color: #666666;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 3px 8px;
}

#my-list > li > a:hover{
    color: black;
}
```

It starts the loop here for the scores. My problem is that I want to be able to display all the scores on one row but it breaks into a new line after each subject is displayed. I want it on a row eg: `Biology ca(10) exam(70) total(100) Economics ca(10) exam(70) total(100)`, till the loop is completed but it keeps breaking into a new line.

```
do{
    echo"<li>";
    echo "<table width='200' border='1'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$dbfieldscore['subject_name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$dbfieldscore['CA']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$dbfieldscore['exam']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$dbfieldscore['total']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</li>";
} while($dbfieldscore=mysql_fetch_assoc($resultscore));
echo "<ul>";
echo "</td>";
```

It loops the database for student score. Here is the problem, I want to display the output horizontally but it goes to the next line.

Comment: Pff.. too much code to read.

Comment: Please post the code relevant to the problem or the code which is generating the undesired output.

Comment: hi...i have reviewd the code to relevent part of the code as requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `white-space:nowrap;` to the `#my-list` rule

```
#my-list{
    background: #f7f7f; 
    padding: 8px; /* Give the items some air to breathe */
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

and to leave the inner contents unaffected you can add

```
#my-list > li {white-space:normal;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace with this, add the spaces to visualize the output in a proper way as per your need.

```
echo "<td>";
do{
     echo $dbfieldscore['subject_name']." ";
     echo "CA: ".$dbfieldscore['CA'];
     echo "Exam: ".$dbfieldscore['exam'];
     echo "Total: ".$dbfieldscore['total'];

   } while($dbfieldscore=mysql_fetch_assoc($resultscore));

echo "</td>";
```